# Control [stop] vertical and horizontal [swipe] motion of GridViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view, wear-os

I have set up a `GridViewpager` in my "MainActivity" that holds various fragments as individual screens for an Android Wear app. My use case requires that both horizontal and vertical motion are allowed on some screens however, some screens should only allow horizontal motion (and likewise only vertical motion) until a certain action is performed.

I looked at some other threads that show how to enable/disable scroll motion completely. However, I want to control both vertical/horizontal motions individually. I've tried to implement it myself but, this implementation seems quite unreliable (when either horizontal or vertical motion is disallowed). Firstly, on repeated attempts it sometime gives a slight jerky motion. Secondly, on screens with primarily large `ImageView` it sometime seems to not work at all when trying to scroll by putting the finger on the ImageView itself (something wrong with `OnInterceptTouchEvent` implementation?).

Here's the code for my "LockableGridViiewPager.java":

```
public class LockableGridViewPager extends GridViewPager {

private boolean verticalScrollable = true;
private boolean horizontalScrollable = true;

float initialX, currentX, dx;
float initialY, currentY, dy;

public boolean isHorizontalScrollable() {
    return horizontalScrollable;
}

public void setHorizontalScrollable(boolean horizontalScrollable) {
    this.horizontalScrollable = horizontalScrollable;
}

public boolean isVerticalScrollable() {
    return verticalScrollable;
}

public void setVerticalScrollable(boolean verticalScrollable) {
    this.verticalScrollable = verticalScrollable;
}

public boolean isScrollable() {
    return isHorizontalScrollable() || isVerticalScrollable();
}

public LockableGridViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public LockableGridViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public LockableGridViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (isScrollable()) {
                initialX = ev.getX();
                initialY = ev.getY();

                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            return isScrollable();

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            currentX = ev.getX();
            currentY = ev.getY();

            dx = Math.abs(currentX - initialX);
            dy = Math.abs(currentY - initialY);

            if (isHorizontalScrollable()) {
                if (dx > dy) {
                    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                }
            }


            if (isVerticalScrollable()) {
                if (dy > dx) {
                    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                }
            }

            return true;


        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return isScrollable() && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can override canScrollHorizontally() and canScrollVertically() and return true or false based on other conditions you have.

Comment: I tried to override these methods in my custom `GridViewPager` class and simply return `false` but it seems to make no change. The official doc doesn't say anything about these functions either. However, `canScrollHorizontally()` is there in official doc of `ViewPager` class and it says the method is there to "check" the scroll functionality. Am I doing it right?